# Error: !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to create frames from the video named `project.avi` and save them to `frameIn` folder. But some type of errors are not let me done. How can I solve this problem. Here is the code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project.avi')

currentFrame = 0

while(True):

ret, frame = cap.read()

name = 'frameIn/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
print ("Creating file... " + name)
cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

frames.append(name)

currentFrame += 1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoreader.py", line 28, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-2rx9f0ng/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:738: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause may be that image is empty, so,
You should check weather video is opened correctly before read frames by: `cap.isOpened()`.
Then, after execute `ret, frame = cap.read()` check `ret` variable value if true to ensure that frame is grabbed correctly.

The code to be Clear :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project.avi')
if cap.isOpened():
    current_frame = 0
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            name = f'frameIn/frame{current_frame}.jpg'
            print(f"Creating file... {name}")
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            frames.append(name)
        current_frame += 1
    cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much thanks thanks thanks. Oh my god! I am searching for this question for a month!

Comment: Thanks ,my pleasure.
but can you please mark this answer as solution ?

Comment: Oh, Sorry! I forgot.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you provided is from OpenCV's imwrite function. It indicates that the function encountered an assertion failure because the input image _img is empty.

In your code snippet, it seems that you are trying to download an image from a URL using wget and then load and save it using OpenCV's imwrite function. However, the error suggests that the image could not be downloaded or read properly, resulting in an empty image.

The error message also includes the line:
code--->
Resolving $image_url ($image_url)... failed: Name or service not known.
This suggests that the variable $image_url has not been properly defined or resolved to a valid URL. Make sure that you have assigned a valid URL to the variable before using it in the wget command.

Additionally, verify that the image was successfully downloaded and that the path to the image file is correct before attempting to load it with OpenCV.

If you provide more details or share the relevant code snippet, I can help you further in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
Tanveer Singh!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).