# imwrite and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgname = r'Images\No Mask\{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

When i run this code i got this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 ret, frame = cap.read()
      3 imgname = r'Images\No Mask\{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
----> 4 cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
      5 cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      7 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

There is a problem but i didn't fix it. I checked on internet but didn't find anything. Can someone help please?

Comment: Your file that you got from the video camera is empty or non-existent. Check the resolution of the file path and be sure it is correct. Either use imgname.shape or cv2.imshow to review your image before writing. Move your cv2.imshow before your cv2.imwrite to see if you get an image. Check the width and height to see if the image is empty. Put a while true test after trying to read the video camera on imgname, testing on the width and height, for example.

Comment: Duplicate of [Error: !\_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648253/error-img-empty-in-function-imwrite)