# I am facing a problem when extracting frames from video. Video have almost 90k frames, codes will show error when 25k frames extracted

Tags: python, opencv, operating-system

Code is here:

```
import cv2
import time
import os

def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        os.mkdir(output_loc)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Write the results back to output location.
        cv2.imwrite(output_loc + "/%#05d.jpg" % (count+1), frame)
        count = count + 1
        # If there are no more frames left
        if (count > (video_length-1)):
            # Log the time again
            time_end = time.time()
            # Release the feed
            cap.release()
            # Print stats
            print ("Done extracting frames.n%d frames extracted" % count)
            print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
            break

if __name__=="__main__":

    input_loc = 'E:/Fish  Project DataSet/06-30/D01_20210630002157.mp4'
    output_loc = 'E:/Fish  Project DataSet/06-30 pictures/D01_20210630002157  frames/'
    video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Displaying error

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Error: !\_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648253/error-img-empty-in-function-imwrite)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Please read the question again. Rana faces this issue only after 25k frames have been read. It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. I wonder if OpenCV has limitations on the number of frames that can be read.

Comment: @JeruLuke You are right, there can be a different problem. But when I searched, I couldnt find a limitation till now. I will follow the topic

Comment: please add results of `ffprobe` on the input video file. I'm betting it's interlaced or has non-constant frame rate. and why are you not checking `if not ret: break`?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because you are trying to write a frame that is empty.

You have to ensure two things:

1. The video is being opened correctly.
2. The frame is being returned correctly.

You can use the following code.

```
import cv2
import time
import os

def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        os.mkdir(output_loc)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    print ("Converting video..n")
    # Start converting the video
    if cap.isOpened():
        count = 0
        # Extract the frame
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                # Write the results back to output location.
                cv2.imwrite(f"{output_loc}{'/%#05d.jpg' % (count + 1)}", frame)
            else:
                print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
                break
            # If there are no more frames left
            count = count + 1
            if (count > (video_length-1)):
                # Log the time again
                time_end = time.time()
                # Release the feed
                cap.release()
                # Print stats
                print ("Done extracting frames.n%d frames extracted" % count)
                print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
                break

if __name__=="__main__":

    input_loc = 'E:/Fish  Project DataSet/06-30/D01_20210630002157.mp4'
    output_loc = 'E:/Fish  Project DataSet/06-30 pictures/D01_20210630002157  frames/'
    video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Please ensure that your video is not corrupted.

Comment: your code may loop forever... because if not ret, count is never incremented, but that's the only branch that breaks the loop. isOpened() will remain True -- I think that much was obvious. the question is about _why_ the input video ends at 25k frames when 90k frames were expected.

Comment: The change in the code will allow to find if the video is corrupted. Apparently this seems to be the case. Your argument regarding the loop seems correct. Let me fix that.