# python opencv does not find raspberry pi camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera

ive got this error i dont have any idea why, i search all the internet and could not find solution

```
[ WARN:0@0.042] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Facial-Recgnition/app/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite("Image.jpg", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Comment: raspi cams aren't necessarily exposed through the V4L interface (/dev/video*). you should research that.

Comment: @TripleS. I tested it and got an error. [ WARN:0@0.251] global /tmp/pip-install-j4z28cif/opencv-python_2bb4d5c379d746d7be275c423c05a9a4/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index. Change index to 0. It should be cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: Try this: import cv2 as cv
    
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imshow('Video',frame)
    cv.imwrite('test.jpg', frame)
    
    key = cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if key==ord('d'):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry but what should i do?

Comment: @toyotaSupra thx for ur reply, it gives me same error,''''[ WARN:0@0.043] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index'''''

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i check i dont have any video0 what should i do?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105733/where-did-dev-video0-go this is purely a raspberry pi OS issue. as long as you don't see any `/dev/video*`, it can't be an OpenCV issue. verify using ffmpeg/VLC/... or `ls /dev/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not uploaded any code snippets, it is difficult for community members to help you. Please attach the code snippet in question and describe the problem in more detail to better understand where the problem is.

Also, I suggest you add a check beforehand to make sure you get a proper return value.

In any case, it seems that the question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648253/error-img-empty-in-function-imwrite).

I hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: sorry im new to stack overflow community, import cv2 
"""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(14)

while cap.isOpened():
   
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   
   cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame)

Comment: The index shold ebe zero not fourteen  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: What's pi model do you have?

Comment: @toyotaSupra 4b 4gb ram

Comment: @toyotaSupra i test 0 too but it said as i shared ""cant open by index"

Comment: I have same both with 4 and 8gb.

Comment: @TripleS try to follow this article: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/